# What is wrong with my code?? perimeter.c

Tags: c

Okay, this is not working!
What is wrong with it.
Can somebody point it out to me. I've stared at it for hours.
I have seeked help earlier and he come up with struct but im not really getting it and it doesnt work so.

It's not getting the right calculation. I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with reading the files.
     /*
     read binary file and calculate parameter of polygon
     */

```
 typedef int16_t points[2];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
// int points[1000];
//long numbytesread=0;
int16_t num_of_coors=0;

//open the files

if( fp == NULL ) {
    printf("Could not open.\n");
    return -1; // -1 indicates error
}

//read file
fread(&num_of_coors, sizeof(int16_t), 2, fp);

points*points=malloc(sizeof(points)*num_of_coors);

fread(points, sizeof(points), num_of_coors, fp);



//read the array and seperate x coordinates and y coordinates
//calculate using formula (x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2
//need 2 points, 4 coordinates at any single time. read a pair at a time

double sum=0;
int i=0;
//int coors=points[0]*2+1 ;

for(i=1;i<=num_of_coors;i++){
    sum+=sqrt(pow((points[i]-points[i+2]),2) + pow((points[i+1]-points[i+3]),2));
}
sum+=sqrt(pow((points[1]-points[num_of_coors-2]),2) + pow((points[2]-points[num_of_coors-1]),2));
printf("The perimeter is %.2lf\n", sum);

fclose(fp);
free(points);
```

}

Comment: In which statement you are getting the error? When you are talking about some error, give the details so that anyone can identify the problem quickly.

Comment: When asking about build errors, always include the actual error in the body of the question, in full, complete, unedited and with any possible informational notes. Also when editing your question to include the error, also please point out *where* in the code you get the errors, for example by adding comments on those lines.

Comment: However, with that said, you have two symbols named `points`, meaning different things. That's not going to work very well.

Comment: I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with the way im reading the files.

Comment: You also have *undefined behavior* once you get the program to build. You read *two* `int16_t` values into the *single* `int16_t` variable `num_of_coors`.

Comment: Change the variable name in `points*points=malloc(sizeof(points)*num_of_coors);
`

Comment: which variables name?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the binary format of your file is:

```
int16_t <num of points>
int16_t <Xcoord> int16_t <Ycoord>
....
```

First, it is bad way to use same name for type name and for variable name.
 Second, you work with 'points' type is incorrect.
 The correct code should looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/*
 read binary file and calculate parameter of polygon
  */

typedef int16_t points[2];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
   // int points[1000];
   //long numbytesread=0;
   int16_t num_of_coors=0;



   //open the files

   if( fp == NULL ) {
       printf("Could not open.\n");
           return -1; // -1 indicates error
    }

           //read file
           fread(&num_of_coors, sizeof(int16_t), 1, fp);

           points* p=malloc(sizeof(points)*num_of_coors);

           fread(p, sizeof(points), num_of_coors, fp);

           //read the array and seperate x coordinates and y coordinates
           //calculate using formula (x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2
           //need 2 points, 4 coordinates at any single time. read a pair at a time

           double sum=0;
           int i=0;
           //int coors=points[0]*2+1 ;

           for(i=1;i<num_of_coors;i++) {
            sum+=sqrt(pow(p[i-1][0]-p[i][0],2)+pow(p[i-1][1]-p[i][1],2));
           }
            sum+=sqrt(pow(p[0][0]-p[num_of_coors-1][0],2)+pow(p[0][1]-p[num_of_coors-1][1],2));
             printf("The perimeter is %.2lf\n", sum);

               fclose(fp);
               free(p);
               return 0;
}
```